# Javascript - вложенность в HTML

Tags: javascript

Скажите плиз, почему при вложении в html --> script дальше второго условия не срабатывает? 
Работает только первое/одно условие, после добавления второго вложенного условия с операторами if.. else.. - браузер при загрузке будто вообще не видит код.
Только так:

```
<script>
var userName = prompt('Кто пришёл?', '');
if (userName == 'Admin');
var pass = prompt('Пароль?', ''); 
</script>
```

Но если добавить ещё несколько условий if.. else.. не срабатывает.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Что означает это If предложение с точкой запятой на конце? Каков его смысл?

Comment: Добавьте ещё несколько условий... Мы посмотрим

Comment: var userName = prompt('Кто пришёл?', '');
    if (userName == 'Admin') {
    
        var pass = prompt('Пароль?', '');
     
     if (pass == ('чёрный кот') {
       alert( 'Добро пожаловать!' );
     } else if (pass == null) {
       alert( 'Вход отменён' );
     } else {
       alert( 'Пароль неверен' );
     }
    } else if (userName == null) {
        alert( 'Вход неверен' );
    } else {
        alert( 'Я вас не знаю' );
    }

Comment: @Nzah В этом предложении не хватает закрывающейся круглой скобки if (pass == ('чёрный кот') {

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>  if (userName == 'Admin');
> ```

Точку с запятой убери.

> после добавления второго вложенного условия с операторами if.. else..

Syntax error `else` без `if` по той же причине.

Comment: Я бы всё-таки ещё посоветовал фигурные скобки добавить

Comment: @andreymal, скобки можно и после `;` добавить, что будет несколько не к месту...

Answer (score 0):

Синтаксис условий таков:

```js
if(something === "somestr"){
//делай что хочешь, пиши что хочешь
}
else if (something !== "somestr"){
//опять же пиши, что хочешь
}
else {
//И тут пиши что хочешь, если ты понимаешь, что это последнее условие.
}
```

И еще хочу обратить твое внимание, что между условиями нельзя создавать переменные, функции, классы и все прочее. Это возможно не повлияет на выполнение твоего кода, но все равно это не делай - это ошибка.

Comment: Брррр... В приведённом примере else никогда не выполнится. А про то, что нельзя создавать между условиями, я не понял. Ни что нельзя, ни где именно.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну это просто пример. Ты можешь менять значение строки до этого логического выражение, и тогда все должно сработать. И я юзаю === , потому что я использую "use strict";.

Comment: Между условными операторами нельзя создавать переменные, классы и функции, иначе будет ошибка  "Unexpected else" или "Unexpected else if".

Comment: "Между" - это где? `if (1) var a=2; else ;` - так можно.

Comment: if(sometring = "asasa"){}

Comment: По-прежнему не понимаю, о чём ты...

Comment: Ну смотри есть условие if  и после него идет else или else if. Между конечной фигурной скобки условия if и словом else нельзя создавать переменные, функции, классы и так далее. И такая же шняга и с else if.

Comment: А, ну это-то да.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я это и имел в виду

Answer (score 0):

```js
var userName = prompt('Ты кто?', '');
if (userName == 'Admin') {
  var pass = prompt('Пароль?', '');
  if (pass == 'чёрный кот') {
    alert('Добро пожаловать!');
  } else if (pass == null) {
    alert('Вход отменён');
  } else {
    alert('Пароль неверен');
  }
} else if (userName == null) {
  alert('Вход неверен');
} else {
  alert('Доступ закрыт');
}
```

С переменными поняла, спасибо! Буду знать..
Но тут или не понимаю чего-то или правда что-то не то... Проверила на ошибки вроде, скобки и всю равно не работает :( Ткните плиз..

Comment: Поправил ваш код

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам ответ :) :) :). Все просто.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var userName = 'Admin'; 
 if (userName == 'Admin') {
 var pass = prompt('Пароль?', '');}
                    if (pass == 'чёрный кот') {
                      alert( 'Добро пожаловать!' );
     document.write("Добро пожаловать" + " " + userName);} 
 
 else if (pass == null) {
                      alert( 'Вход отменён' );} 
 
 else if (userName == null) {
                    alert( 'Вход неверен' );} 
 
 else if (pass != 'черный кот') {alert( 'Пароль неверен' );} 
 else {alert( 'Доступ закрыт' );
   document.write("Ты кто такой?")}
</script>
```

Comment: Я бы вам еще посоветовал (если есть возможность использовать Adobe Dreamweaver(знаю дорого, но программа супер, конечно вы её можете крякнуть при желании)). Она указывает на все ошибки в коде (иногда даже слишком точная на ошибки) будь-то html или css или javascript (и jQuery и Angular JS) и PHP. Супер программа, очень доволен.